# How do you get a total count for each events in between each full hour?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a sum total of `units` and `hours` for each `task` for each hour of the day. Some tasks extend across hours, but i want to know what counted towards each hour.

Sample of my table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1790e/1/0

```
|  login   |   task    |  start_time           |  end_time             |  units |  hours |
| -------- | --------- |  -------------------- | --------------------- | ------ | ------ |
|  Johnny  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 10:15:55  |  2021-07-08 10:23:20  |  53    |  0.13  |
|  Johnny  |  damaged  |  2021-07-08 10:23:20  |  2021-07-08 10:30:40  |  24    |  0.12  |
|  Johnny  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 10:30:40  |  2021-07-08 11:35:01  |  342   |  1.08  |
|  Johnny  |  damaged  |  2021-07-08 11:35:01  |  2021-07-08 11:47:34  |  37    |  0.2   |
|  Johnny  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 11:47:34  |  2021-07-08 11:59:59  |  68    |  0.2   |
|  Meghan  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 09:04:13  |  2021-07-08 09:36:54  |  152   |  0.53  |
|  Meghan  |  damaged  |  2021-07-08 09:36:54  |  2021-07-08 09:41:37  |  7     |  0.08  |
|  Meghan  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 09:41:37  |  2021-07-08 10:52:27  |  390   |  1.01  |
|  Meghan  |  damaged  |  2021-07-08 10:52:27  |  2021-07-08 10:54:36  |  2     |  0.03  |
|  Meghan  |  receive  |  2021-07-08 10:54:36  |  2021-07-08 11:23:55  |  198   |  0.48  |
|  Meghan  |  pack     |  2021-07-08 11:23:55  |  2021-07-08 11:59:59  |  89    |  0.6   |
|  Terry   |  receive  |  2021-07-08 09:02:49  |  2021-07-08 11:32:01  |  1012  |  2.5   |
|  Terry   |  end      |  2021-07-08 11:32:01  |  2021-07-08 11:59:59  |  0     |  0.46  |
```

Above, `login` Terry leaves the system early, so that time counts as effectively 0 from that point.

All i know so far is to pull out the starting hour time to start grouping

```
SELECT login,task,extract(hour from start_time) AS Start_Hour,start_time,end_time,units,hours
FROM table1
group by start_hour, task, units
```

Combining each users time spent on the task, and unit count, how can i get a sum output for each `start_hour` worth of `task` ?

Example of output I am trying for, taking END out as its not effective hours.

```
| start_hour |   task    |  units |  hours |
| ---------- | --------- | ------ | ------ |
|     9      | damaged   |   7    | 0.08   |
|     9      | receive   |   658  | 1.80   |
|     9      | pack      |   0    | 0.00   |
|     10     | damaged   |   26   | 0.08   |
|     10     | receive   |   985  | 2.58   |
|     10     | pack      |   0    | 0.00   |
|     11     | damaged   |   37   | 0.15   |
|     11     | receive   |   623  | 1.72   |
|     11     | pack      |   89   | 0.60   |
```

Comment: how have you calculated this ? 9      | receive   |   658  | 1.80

Comment: your output calculation is confusing for received and hours. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Its calculated by converting units per hour into units per minute, then figuring out how man minutes took place for the task during that hour for each line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be doing what is needed

```
SELECT extract(hour from start_time) AS Start_Hour, task, SUM(units) AS total_units, SUM(hours) AS total_hours
FROM table1
WHERE task <> 'end'
GROUP BY Start_Hour, task;
```

Comment: no it doesn't at all http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1790e/20

Comment: yep, it does;  sum totals of units and hours for each task for each hour of the day.

Comment: please chack the question he want fpr al hours all three tasks and clearly 15ßß is no 658

Comment: *Combining each users time spent on the task, and unit count, how can i get a sum output for each start_hour worth of task ?*. Still looks to me like the above is what is needed, no matter what the dummy values in the output he is trying for has.

Comment: You see in the comments that the question is unclear. Still the user wants all thre tags per hou. That is consistent

Comment: What I see in the comments is not that the question is unclear but that the sample output given is inconsistent. What I did was simply answer the question regardless of the sample output provided.

Comment: this doesn't give the right answer. there can't possibly be 4+ hours of a task during a time of which only 2 users were present. my example is taking the units done per hour and turning it into minutes, to determine how many would have been done during that hour.  example. Terry received 1012 units over 2.5 hours, or 6.75 / minute. so the first hour has 384.75 units from just Terry. my example output rounded some numbers